# How do I get total SUM of columns

Tags: sql, oracle

Do any of you know how to get total sum for each column in a table. And how I do this no matter how many columns there are in the table.?

Comment: You should post samples of data and desired result together with your approach to resolve the issue

Comment: Pls give an example for your question.

Answer (score 1):

try this, for example table has 2 columns..

```
SELECT SUM(col1) AS S1,SUM(col2) AS S2 
FROM table_name;
```

Comment: Yep :) no prob... but how do I do this if I dont know how many collums and what there names are? Any method to dertermine all cullum names ?

Answer (score 0):

To get all the columns in a table, you can use

```
SELECT DISTINCT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME='your table name'
```

You could then write some dynamic SQL to use this list of column names to build the SELECT statement as outlined in the first answer (uma_SF answer)

Comment: Gets a message saying that view or table doesnt exist... :( Dont get it cause I know the tbl exists

Comment: Can you post the exact SQL you tried please and the error message

Comment: SELECT DISTINCT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME= 'ORDRE_SPEC2'; This was your code with my table name inserted... this is the error : Error starting at line 1 in command:
SELECT DISTINCT(COLUMN_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME= 'ORDRE_SPEC2'
Error at Command Line:1 Column:54
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"
*Cause:    
*Action:

Comment: try this.
select column_name from all_tab_columns where table_name = 'table name';

Comment: Was this an Oracle database? Would probably help people answer your problem if you tagged your question correctly